# CLLocationManager don't receive updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation

I'am new in Objective-C world. I try developing simple location application on iOS 6.1 on simulator. But when i try simulate location it doesn't work at all. I don't receive any event, but `delegate` object is registered properly and `PositionProvider` is `startUpdate`.

What is wrong?

I have following code:

**PositionProvider**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "LocationListener.h"

@interface PositionProvider : NSObject
{
    @public
    LocationListener<CLLocationManagerDelegate> *listener;
    @protected
    CLLocationManager *manager;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark on/off

-(void) startUpdate;

-(void) stopUpdate;

@end
```

*Implementation*

```
    @implementation PositionProvider
{
@private
    CLLocation *lastLocation;
}

-(void) startUpdate{
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    LocationListener *listener2 = [[LocationListener alloc]init];

    manager.delegate = listener2;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if(manager == nil)
        NSLog(@"Manager is NULL");

    if(listener == nil || manager.delegate == nil)
        NSLog(@"Listener is NULL");

    NSLog(@"startUpdate");

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");
        switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"We have access to location services");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"Location services denied by user");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"Parental controls restrict location services");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"Unable to determine, possibly not available");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Location Services Are Disabled");
    }

    [manager startUpdatingHeading];
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void) stopUpdate{



}

@end
```

**LocationListener**

```
@interface LocationListener : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;



    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;

@end
```

*Implementation*

```
@implementation LocationListener 

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

//    newLocation.coordinate;

    NSLog(@"Logging Location");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    NSLog(@"Logging Location");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus) status{


    NSLog(@"Status");
}

@end
```

Comment: Why he are a variable named listener2 and an other (ivar) named listener ?

Comment: @tdelepine It was changed only in debugging purpose. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you use a wifi network sometimes the user location is wrong ? 
In this case it's necessary to go in the simulator menu and sets more times the location

Comment: @tdelepin Location is not wrong, it is't updated at all. I try change location multiple time, change  GPS "route". It don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
[manager setDelegate:listener2];
```

Alternatively, you may have a memory management issue. Try adding the dealloc method with a debugger-breakpoint and see if it gets called before you expected:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Dealloc called");

    self.locationManager = nil;
}
```